# appending an array in while loop and if condition

Tags: python, arrays, if-statement, arraylist, while-loop

```
n = -12
while n < 15:
    if n < 0:
        dgt = []
        dgt.append(n)
    n = n+1
print(dgt)
```

I am trying to append all negative values in dgt[] but what I get from this code `[-1]` which is not my result I want all negative valuse in dgt[] please help me.

Comment: You are initialising the list inside the loop over and over

Comment: The list creation `dgt = []` should be done *before* the while loop.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk and Dani Mesejo Thank you sooo much for helping me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reinitialising the list `dgt` for every loop iteration. Move it outside the loop.

```
n = -12
dgt = []
while n < 15:
    if n < 0:
        dgt.append(n)
    n = n+1
print(dgt)
```

Answer (score 1):

also you know you can do it without loop :

```
n = -12
dgt = [n+i for i in range(-n)]
print(dgt)
```